# Sapphire HD 7870 Ghz Quad monitors support

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Does Sapphire HD 7870 Ghz support 4 monitors simultaneously (independently and without mirroring or stretching any one of them), that is :
1 TV through HDMI cable
2 monitor using miniHD to HD converter
1 monitor through DVI

I read that DVI port is shared internally with HD port and only one of them works at the same time

However , some says that it would work with quad monitors setup!

Please help.